# How to call Make from Meson?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, meson-build

I'm using [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) to build a project.

The project now needs a dependency to another library, which is easily built using Make, just by issuing the `make` command.

I would like to add this as a subproject dependency in Meson. Is it possible to call Make from Meson's `meson.build` file? How is it done?

Comment: [`custom_target`](https://mesonbuild.com/Custom-build-targets.html)? [`run_target`](https://mesonbuild.com/Run-targets.html)? [The experimental external project module](https://mesonbuild.com/External-Project-module.html)?

Comment: Thanks for pointers, will try that.

Comment: You might want the `external_project` module